# Why parent coroutine is not canceled?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, coroutine, event-loop

I'm playing with Python `asyncio`. My program has only three coroutines. Two of them I schedule directly while the third one is scheduled from one of the formers. And I want to finalize my program properly when user presses `Ctrl+C`:

```
import asyncio

async def coro1():
    try:
        print('coro1')
        await asyncio.sleep(1000)
    except Exception as e:
        print('coro1 exc %s' % repr(e))
        raise

async def coro2():
    try:
        print('coro2')
        await asyncio.ensure_future(coro3())
        await asyncio.sleep(1000)
    except Exception as e:
        print('coro2 exc %s' % repr(e))
        raise

async def coro3():
    try:
        print('coro3')
        await asyncio.sleep(1000)
    except Exception as e:
        print('coro3 exc %s' % repr(e))
        raise

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()    
try:
    f1 = asyncio.ensure_future(coro1())
    f2 = asyncio.ensure_future(coro2())    
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Exiting... Cancelling all tasks')

    f2.cancel()
    f1.cancel()

    # This code gives the same result:
    # for task in asyncio.tasks.Task.all_tasks(loop):
    #    task.cancel()

    print('Cancellation is done!')

    loop.stop()
    loop.run_forever()
finally:
    loop.close()
```

This code produces the next output:

```
coro1
coro2
coro3
^CExiting... Cancelling all tasks
Cancellation is done!
coro3 exc CancelledError()
coro1 exc CancelledError()
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<coro2() running at test.py:15> wait_for=<Task cancelled coro=<coro3() done, defined at test.py:23>>>
```

So I wonder, why `coro2` was not canceled and `coro3` actually **was** canceled?

Comment: Coroutine 2 sleeps an additional 1000 seconds after coroutine 3 returns. Try with a shorter duration of sleep (or wait 1000s!)

Comment: @shongololo, I'm afraid that even if I'll delete `await sleep(1000)` at all, the observed behaviour won't change.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the lowest lines of your code sample (hidden by scroll). It might be that coroutine 2 isn't getting the chance to return the exception and shut-down by the time the loop closes down. You can wait to check that all tasks are cancelled before shutting the loop, but then you won't see your exceptions in action...

Comment: @shongololo looks like I found the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it! The problem was in these two lines in the `except` block:

```
# ...
loop.stop()
loop.run_forever()
```

Expected cancelation propagation didn't work due to `loop.stop()`. If one change the code to something like this:

```
# ...

try:
    f1 = asyncio.ensure_future(coro1())
    f2 = asyncio.ensure_future(coro2())    
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Exiting... Cancelling all tasks')
    f2.cancel()
    f1.cancel()
    print('Cancellation is done!')    
    try:
        loop.run_forever()
        # Wait a very short time for f2 cancelation and press Ctrl+C again.
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        loop.stop()
        loop.run_forever()
finally:
    loop.close()
```

the message `Task was destroyed but it is pending!` would go away.

A little bit nicer way would be using `loop.run_until_complete()` approach:

```
f1 = asyncio.ensure_future(coro1())
f2 = asyncio.ensure_future(coro2())
tasks = asyncio.gather(f1, f2)
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Exiting... Cancelling all tasks')
    tasks.cancel()  # or f1.cancel(); f2.cancel()
    print('Cancellation is done!')

    loop.run_forever()
    tasks.exception()  # To skip '_GatheringFuture exception was never retrieved' warning
finally:
    loop.close()
```

`run_until_complete` adds internal callback that will stop the loop after finishing (or cancelling) all tasks.